# How to cast elements of collection without converting to IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, linq

I am creating a suite of interfaces for my Entity Framework entity classes to implement.  I want to expose the `ICollection<T>` properties of the entity classes without converting them to another type like `IEnumerable<T>`.

```
public interface IConversation
{
    ICollection<IDialogue> Dialogue { get; }
}

public partial class Conversation : IConversation
{
    public ICollection<IDialogue> Dialogue
    {
        get { return ConversationDialogues as ICollection<IDialogue>; }
    }
    //type of ConversationDialogues is ICollection<Dialogue>
}

public partial class Dialogue : IDialogue
{
    //Members
}
```

The problem is that I cannot simply cast `ConversationDialogues` to `ICollection<IDialogue>`.  I cannot use `ConversationDialogues.Cast<IDialogue>` because `Cast<T>()` returns an IEnumerable.  I could call `ToList()` but I would prefer not to do this if it is not necessary.

Comment: Why would you prefer not to call `ToList()`? You want to convert a collection to a new collection of a different type, why would you want to avoid using `Cast` into `ToList` or `ToArray`?

Comment: public interface ICollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>, 
    IEnumerable

ICollection implements IEnumerable so why not?

Comment: I don't want to call .ToList() because on large collections this could be costly.  I know that premature optimization is the bane of all development etc., but I want this solution to be scale-able.  I also do not want to use an IEnumerable<T> for similar reasons: it does not expose the same members as an ICollection and I would have to call .ToList() in many cases anyways.

Comment: Can we see the declaration of `ConversationDialogues` ? Why can't you cast it to `ICollection<T>` ? If you assign an `ICollection<T>` to it, then you should be able to cast it that way.

Comment: Have you actually demonstrated that it isn't scalable in some way? I've seen (and participated in) plenty of scenarios where prematurely optimizing for something made things slow. Often it is a result of developers thinking too far ahead on their goal.

Comment: @CBauer I am basing it on this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186268/entity-framework-select-new-poco-without-tolist-first/5187571#5187571   And from (admittedly second hand) talk from an architect in my area.  That's not to say it will ever be relevant, and I am one of the first people to throw out microsecond optimizations in favor of simplicity and extendability, but the fact that it wasn't an isolated statement makes me want to look for another solution if possible.  If it isn't possible, then .ToList() will have to be acceptable.

Comment: Well explicitly calling .ToList() will materialize the entire entity, basically performing the sql operation that the lambda represents. That's why you avoid calling tolist on the entity until the last possible moment. If you need to interact with the data in any way, it makes sense to return the IQueryable<T> of your collection after applying logic so that you can continue to write linq against it until you have what you need. Then you can materialize the results using .ToList(). However, returning the IQueryable<T>() is as simple as calling .AsQueryable().

Comment: Using IQueryable<T> over IEnumerable<T> is acceptable to me as I didn't need anything like .ForEach() to be exposed, if you submit I will take that as an answer.